# How to rotate or scale 3D model scn file in AR kit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

this class render my SCN file as well.

```
import UIKit
import ARKit

class SimpleViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene(named: "duck.scn", inDirectory: "models.scnassets/furniture")!
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        sceneView.session.run(ARWorldTrackingConfiguration())
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }
}
```

but I know how can I rotate or scale my object (`duck.scn`) file. I would like to user can do interaction with my object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to scale an `SCNNode` you can do something like this:

```
/// Scales An SCNNode
///
/// - Parameter gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer
@objc func scaleObject(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let nodeToScale = currentNode else { return }
    if gesture.state == .changed {

        let pinchScaleX: CGFloat = gesture.scale * CGFloat((nodeToScale.scale.x))
        let pinchScaleY: CGFloat = gesture.scale * CGFloat((nodeToScale.scale.y))
        let pinchScaleZ: CGFloat = gesture.scale * CGFloat((nodeToScale.scale.z))
        nodeToScale.scale = SCNVector3Make(Float(pinchScaleX), Float(pinchScaleY), Float(pinchScaleZ))
        gesture.scale = 1

    }
    if gesture.state == .ended { }

}
```

Whereby current node refers to an `SCNNode`.

If you want to move an `SCNNode` you can do something like this:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    //1. Get The Current Touch Point
    guard let currentTouchPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView),
        //2. Get The Next Feature Point Etc
        let hitTest = augmentedRealityView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, types: .existingPlane).first else { return }

    //3. Convert To World Coordinates
    let worldTransform = hitTest.worldTransform

    //4. Set The New Position
    let newPosition = SCNVector3(worldTransform.columns.3.x, worldTransform.columns.3.y, worldTransform.columns.3.z)

    //5. Apply To The Node
    currentNode.simdPosition = float3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z)

}
```

If you would like to rotate an `SCNNode` you first should create a variable(s) to store the original angle e.g:

```
//Store The Rotation Of The CurrentNode
var currentAngleY: Float = 0.0
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
/// Rotates An SCNNode Around It's YAxis
///
/// - Parameter gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer
@objc func rotateNode(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer){

    //1. Get The Current Rotation From The Gesture
    let rotation = Float(gesture.rotation)

    //2. If The Gesture State Has Changed Set The Nodes EulerAngles.y
    if gesture.state == .changed{

        currentNode.eulerAngles.y = currentAngleY + rotation
    }

    //3. If The Gesture Has Ended Store The Last Angle Of The Cube
    if(gesture.state == .ended) {
        currentAngleY = currentNode.eulerAngles.y

    }
}
```

If you want to interact directly with your SCNScene (although I believe not in ARKit) you can use the following method:

```
var allowsCameraControl: Bool { get set }
```

Whereby:

> If you set this property to true, SceneKit creates a camera node and
>   handles mouse or touch events to allow the user to pan, zoom, and
>   rotate their view of the scene. (Enabling user camera control does not
>   modify camera objects already existing in the scene graph or the nodes
>   containing them.)

An example would thus be:

```
 sceneView.scene = SCNScene(named: "duck.scn", inDirectory: "models.scnassets/furniture")!
 sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true;
```